# Cannot convert Time in the desired DateTime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, ipython, jupyter

I am new to pandas and I am trying to convert Time into DateTime format. Unfortunately I get the time with an added date which is not my intention.

My dataFrame is the following: [image]

After running `data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Time'], format = '%H:%M:%S')` I get the following: [image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: DateTime is a binary value, it has no format. Formats apply only when parsing strings into Datetime or formatting Datetime for display. A DateTime always has a `date` component too, so perhaps you should use `time` instead of `datetime` ?

Comment: You could use `datetime.time` to extract the time part of the parsed datetime

Comment: you're doing nothing wrong, it's just that with pandas' datetime datatype, you can't have only date or only time, it's always both. To get only the time, you can use `data['Time'] = data['Time'].dt.time` - but note that this will leave you with a column of datatype 'object', Python datetime.time objects to be precise. Alternatively, you could just leave it as string. It depends on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = {'time':['05:05:30','06:04:23','03:40:45','12:05:30'], 'value':[2,3,5,7]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data['TIME']=pd.to_datetime(data['time'],format='%H:%M:%S')
```

you get TIME in the desired format:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype          
---  ------  --------------  -----          
 0   time    4 non-null      object         
 1   value   4 non-null      int64          
 2   TIME    4 non-null      timedelta64[ns]
dtypes: int64(1), object(1), timedelta64[ns](1)
```

[image]

Comment: why would you parse to datetime, just to convert back to string straight away?

Comment: @MrFuppes True. i Used the previous version in a case where I also had dates with the time. Thanks!